# How to get the paragraph information in a custom display suite code item

Tags: 7, paragraphs

I want to add a custom field for a paragraph item in display suite,
but I don't know the name of variable.

I try a `print_r($entity)` and nothing is returned. How can I find out what the object name is?

Comment: Are you using the [paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) module?

Comment: Yes I am using that

Comment: Not sure if I understand your Q correctly. So I will just throw this out there. You can add fields by going to Structure >> Paragraph Bundles then click on manage fields (assuming you already have a bundle, if not create one, then manage fields).

Comment: I know how to add them . I want to know how to display them in a specific way . So I want to use a custom display suite code field

Comment: I'm using a view and want to display the first paragraph of text type and the first paragraph of data type . But only the first one . Currently they all come out in the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm using a view and want to display the first paragraph of text type
>   and the first paragraph of data type . But only the first one .
>   Currently they all come out in the view

In Views click on your paragraph field, mine is called "test".

Then in Multiple Field Settings, change Display to `1`

[image]

Comment: thanks but i also want the first paragraph of type "text" and the first paragraph of type "image"  .  how do i do that

Comment: This should do that. Exactly how did you setup your stuff? This is what I did. In content type Article, I added a paragraph field with Unlimited values. Then in bundle I added a text field with 1 value and an image field with 1 value.

Comment: how do you add those bundles to the view?  I can only add fields

Comment: @Dianacastillo I'm not talking about the view, in Structure >> Paragraph Bundles,  added a text field with 1 value and an image field with 1 value. Then all I did was add the paragraph field from Article, to the view.

Comment: no I need individual paragraphs of type either "image " or "text"  since they can add unlimited amounts of each , in different orders

Comment: @Dianacastillo I saw you accepted my answer ✅, problem solved?

Comment: you helped me with one part of the answer but i asked the other part here . thanks http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224065/how-to-show-paragraph-bundles-of-different-types-in-a-view

Comment: @Dianacastillo If your bundle contains 1 field of text and 1 field of image, this answer should display you the first of text and the first of image.

Comment: no I want separate bundles , one with only text, one with an image and other things

Comment: @Dianacastillo oh **separate bundles**, ok, I see.