# How to show paragraph bundles of different types in a view of content containing paragraphs?

Tags: 7, paragraphs

I am using the [Paragraphs](http://drupal.org/project/paragraphs) module and I want to show the paragraphs of one type at the beginning of the view and the paragraph of a different type at the end. How do I distinguish paragraphs of different types (since the field name is the same)?

I see that they are doing it here but my view doesn't have those options : 
https://www.drupal.org/node/2592021

ALSO I want to be able to insert this view of paragraphs into a view of the corresponding content. How can I do that?

Comment: Is your base view of Paragraphs, or Node? Might explain why some options are missing.

Comment: @Diana did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a brand new view. Go to `/admin/structure/views/add`

For **Show:** select `Paragraph Items`

Once in the View, add fields, and you should be able to add `Paragraphs item: [Name]`

> but I want to see the content that has these paragraphs, not just the
>   paragraphs

Then you will need to use [Views Fields View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) to **embed this view as a field** in your other (node) view.

You will need to add a contextual filter of nid (to this paragraphs view).

Now in our other view (Node view) add views embed view as a field.

I think there is an option (checkbox) to automatically pass the contextual filter of your current node view to the embed view.

If not, simply add nid as a field in your node view, then when you add the view embed view field, use the replacement pattern of the nid as contextual filter.

Comment: but I want to see the content that has these paragraphs, not just the paragraphs

Comment: That is what the views field view part is for. 1) Create a view of content that contains paragraphs. 2) One of the fields or that view should be another view that displays paragraph content for each individual node. If you don't have a good grasp on how this works, I recommend looking for a tutorial on the `Views Field View` module.